# Creating hash function to map 6 numbers to a short string

Tags: algorithm, hash, mapping

I have 6 variables `0 ≤ n₁,...,n₆ ≤ 12` and I'd like to build a hash function to do the direct mapping `D(n₁,n₂,n₃,n₄,n₅,n₆) = S` and another function to do the inverse mapping `I(S) = (n₁,n₂,n₃,n₄,n₅,n₆)`, where S is a string (a-z, A-Z, 0-9).

My goal is to minimize the length of S for 3 or less.

I thought as the variables have 13 possible values, a single letter (a-z) should be able to represent 2 of them, but I realized that `1 + 12 = m` and `2 + 11 = m`, so I still don't know how to write a function.

Is there any approach to build a function that does this mapping and returns a small string?

Using the whole ASCII to represent S is an option if it's necessary.

Comment: Can you give an example, like Input of 6 numbers and their hash = $56 ... but my question is will there always be 6 numbers present ?

Comment: 12^6=144^3 > 125^3，you can't. Maybe I was wrong.

Comment: @zenwraight you are right, D(1,2,3,4,5,6) = X8% could be a possibility

Comment: @Silencer can you explain how did u come up with those number ?

Comment: 12^6 (in fact I think he meant 13^6) is the number of possibilities for the input variables, 125^3 means that isnt possible with 125 chars from ASCII to represent those possibilities with only 3 chars

Comment: What does "D(1,2,3,4,5,6) = X8%" mean?

Comment: means the direct mapping of n1...n2 with values 1...6 could return the string X8%

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a set of numbers in any given range to numbers in any other range using **base conversion**.

Binary is base 2 (0-1), decimal is base 10 (0-9). Your 6 numbers are base 13 (0-12).

Checking whether a conversion would be possible involves counting the number of possible combinations of values for each set. With each number in the range [0,n] (thus base n+1), we can go from all 0's to all n's, thus each number can take on n+1 values and the total number of possibilities is (n+1)<sup>numberCount</sup>. For 6 decimal digits, for example, it would be 10<sup>6</sup> = 1000000, which checks out, since there are 1000000 possible numbers with (at most) 6 digits, i.e. numbers < 1000000.

Lower- and uppercase letters and numbers (26+26+10) would be base 62 (0-61), but, following from the above, 3 such values would be insufficient to represent your 6 numbers (13<sup>6</sup> > 62<sup>3</sup>). To do conversion from/to these, you can do the conversion to a set of base 62 numbers, then have appropriate if-statements to convert 0-9 <=> 0-9, a-z <=> 10-35, A-Z <=> 36-61.

You can represent your data in 3 bytes (since 256<sup>3</sup> >= 13<sup>6</sup>), although this wouldn't necessary be printable characters - 32-126 is considered the standard printable range (which is still too small of a range), 128-255 is the extended range and may not be displayed properly in any given environment (to give the best chance of properly displaying it, you should at least avoid 0-31 and 127, which are control characters - you can convert 0-... to the above ranges by adding 32 and then adding another 1 if the value is >= 127).

Many / most languages should allow you to give a numeric value to represent a character, so it should be fairly simple to output it once you do the base conversion. Although some may use Unicode to represent characters, which could make it a bit less trivial to work with ASCII.

If the numbers had **specific constraints**, that would reduce the number of possible combinations, thus possibly making it fit into a smaller set or range of numbers.

### To do the actual base conversion:

It might be simplest to first convert it to a regular integral type (typically binary or decimal), where we don't have to worry about the base, and then convert it to the target base (although first make sure your value will fit in whichever data type you're using).

Consider how binary works:

```
1101 is 13 = 23 + 22 + 20

13 % 2 = 1   13 / 2 = 6
6  % 2 = 0    6 / 2 = 3
3  % 2 = 1    3 / 2 = 1
1  % 2 = 1
The above, from top to bottom: 1101 = our number
```

Using the same idea, we can convert to/from any base as follows: (pseudo-code)

```java
int convertFromBase(array, base):
   output = 0
   for each i in array
      output = base*output + i
   return output

int[] convertToBase(num, base):
   output = []
   while num > 0
      output.append(num % base)
      num /= base
   output.reverse()
   return output
```

You can also extend this logic to situations where each number is in a different range by changing what you divide or multiple by at each step (a detailed explanation of that is perhaps a bit beyond the scope of the question).

Answer (score 0):

> I thought as the variables have 13 possible values, a single letter
>   (a-z) should be able to represent 2 of them

This reasoning is wrong. In fact to represent two variables (=any combination these variables might take) you will need 13x13 = 169 symbols.

For your example the 6 variables can take 13^6 (=4826809) different combinations. In order to represent all possible combinations you will need 5 letters (a-z) since 26^5 (=11881376) is the least amount that is will yield more than 13^6 combinations.

For ASCII characters 3 symbols should suffice since 256^3 > 13^6.

If you are still interested in code that does the conversion, I will be happy to help.

Comment: Depends how you define ASCII. The original ASCII was 7 bit, yielding only 128 possible characters. Taking into account that about 30 or so are non-printable, that leaves you with less than a hundred to work with.